# How to scan all ports in nmap

Tags: nmap

I didn't get what ports does Nmap scan. Does Nmap start from zero or one when scan subnet or all the ports?

- 0/24 is it 0-255 or is it 1-255
- -p is it 0-65535 or is it 1-65535

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connecting to port 0 is not possible, see

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/180500/85039

It is a special port allowing programs to obtain random port for outgoing connection, and should not be used for incoming connections

Therefore, use `-p 1-65535` for `nmap`, especially if you are using TCP or UDP scans

As for `/24` notation that is entirely different thing: it is called [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) notation and used to match range of hosts on network. For instance, 192.168.0.0/24 will specify all addresses between 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.0.255

Comment: but i can scan all ports in nmap using the command -p 0-65535

Comment: so /24 start with zero not one ?

Comment: @VenVen You can use `-p 0-65535`. But trying to scan port 0 is pointless - it's never open to outside world, only to programs on the host itself.

Comment: As for `/24`, yes, address range starts at 0 and goes to 255. That's 256 hosts in total theoretically. But remember that in practice 192.168.0.255 is broadcast address for the whole 192.168.0.0/24 network. Typically it's not used for a host and `ping` utility for example will throw an error, but it is perfectly valid address. On a different subnet other than `/24`, it could be a perfectly valid host.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/14915309/3701431 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407395/85039

Answer (score 0):

Nmap can scan all TCP UDP ports. You must to know subnetting and network knowledge. 0 port is not a standart port. For subnet if you use 24 subnetmask you will not scan 192.168.0.0 address because 24 subnetmask have a useable range for hosts. 0.0 is out of subnet useable scope.
You can learn from here: http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/subnetting-subnet-masks-explained/